# How can I find the references of a class, method, variable in Emacs with Etags?

Tags: eclipse, emacs, etag

I'd like to find all the references to a class, method, variable in Emacs, the same way I'm able to do it in Eclipse with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+G</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd+Shift+G</kbd> on the Mac) once I've setup my project's ETags.

I can navigate the code fine, but finding references to things is key to understanding large code bases, I'm sure this must be possible in Emacs but I can't find anything about it, maybe an Emacs expert will know right away.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this what you are looking for? http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is an M-x rgrep . The TAGS file lists the definition of the tags only, not who references it.